# Kill previous session if the same user logged in again wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there an option to destroy all other user session after a user logs in. I found an option for destroying sessions as

```
 // get all sessions for user with ID $user_id
    $sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user->ID );
    // we have got the sessions, destroy them all!
    $sessions->destroy_all();
```

It can use on authenticating a user, but I am using a social login plugin for authenticating users, so need to hack the plugin for achieving the same. Can you help me figure out an option to destroy all previous sessions on or after "wp_login" action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved it!!.
destroy_all() will destroy all  the sessions so when we are use this in wp_login hook it will destroy the current session too, instead we can use destroy_others() function. 
The final code shown below

```
    function your_function( $user,$user_id) {
        $sessions  = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( get_current_user_id() );
        $token = wp_get_session_token();

        $sessions->destroy_others( $token  );
    }
    add_action('wp_login', 'your_function',10,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hook into the wp_login action. Could be done in the plugin or in your functions.php

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    // your code
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login